# invoke-rc.d: could not determine the current runlevel

Tags: mysql

I uninstalled MySQL because I was having a problem with the root user password not working. Now I can't reinstall. I've tried reading through some similar posts but frankly they're beyond my level or not quite what I'm dealing with. Here's the full output of commands used:

```
bigbossNP@LenovoY2P:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server                                                                
[sudo] password for bigbossNP:                                                                                          
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to 
correct the problem.                       
bigbossNP@LenovoY2P:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a                                                                         
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...                                                               
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel                                                                        
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld      [ OK ]                                                       
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)                                                     
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel                                                                       
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel                                                                        
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld      [ OK ]
```

After this I don't get the command prompt back so I have to shut down the terminal and reopen. What do I need to do to get it reinstalled and running correctly again?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the full output of the commands you ran

Answer (score 3):

0) I am guessing you have tried 
    sudo apt-get install -f

1) Back up your existing MySQL files.  You can find out where your data directory is in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402884/where-does-mysql-store-data

You can use mysqldump to backup.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-back-up-mysql-databases-from-the-command-line-with-linux/

2) Run these commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'mysql*'
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Every time I use sudo it results in the same request to manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' which leads to the errors listed in my original post. Every fix I've found has required use of sudo command. At this point would it work to completely uninstall everything (down to Ubuntu) and start over?? If so can someone direct me to an article showing how to do that?

Comment: What is the output of ps aux | grep dpkg

Comment: @TheCabDriverCheatedMeToday Having the same issue in Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you very much.